# apc_fetch() and apc_store() usage in php

Tags: php, apc

What's the usage of `apc_store();` and `apc_fetch();` on the following example?

```
function getData($uid){
    $cached = apc_fetch($uid);
    return $cached?$cached:"Start";
}

function setData($uid,$step){
    apc_store($uid,$step,60*60*12);
}
```

I want to store string and then use it later. I can't understand the main and general explanations about these two functions in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method `getData($uid)` simply returns the value of $uid from cache and if there is not variable for the key $uid then it will returns a string "Start". So simply returns the value of $uid from cache.

And the second method `setData($uid,$step)` defines a variable in cache as $uid storing the value as $step with **ttl 60*60*12.**

TTL is the time that defines life of the cached variable **$uid.**
(Time To Live; store var in the cache for ttl seconds.)

```
apc_store($key,$val,$time_in_seconds);
//This method stores variable in alternative PHP cache and this is used for performance.
```

For more detail, see:

1. [apc_store()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php)
2. [apc_fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php)

Also take a look at [apc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)